# Can I query a Cloud Firestore collection with a where equals clause and an orderby?

Tags: database, firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) states:

> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field:

That implies that I can use the non-range comparison, "==", with the orderBy clause.  But this fails:

```
myCollectionRef.where('age', '==', 2).orderBy('name');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to order a query with one or more equality filters, where the ordering is by a different field, you'll need to create a composite index.

You can read more about this in our ["Managing Indexes"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) documentation section.

Comment: Thank you.  Is this feature a candidate for future development?  the ability to have equality filters, plus ordering on a different field, without composite indices?  Or unlikely...?  I notice that it is possible to use multiple equality filters without requiring custom indices.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We can use different techniques for equality filters

Comment: What different techniques we can follow for these types of query? Can you help me in solving this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874499/structuring-firebase-firestore-for-e-commerce-filter-functionality?noredirect=1#comment80696315_46874499