# Structuring Firebase Firestore for E-commerce Filter functionality

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says, I want to achieve the filter functionality with my E-Commerce app fully built on Firebase Firestore.

The filter could be too complex like - List of products (e.g. phones) with

```
- price range between 10k - 20k
- Brands among Samsung, Motorola and Apple
- OS should be Marshmallow, Nougat or Oreo
- RAM should be 3GB, 4GB or 6GB
```

Since complex queries are not possible directly, it is clear that I need to restructure my DB. Please help me in restructuring part or if you have any other suggestions, I would love to hear.

As of now I have done

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("products")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("price", 10000)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("price", 20000)
    .whereEqualTo("brand", "Samsung")
    .whereEqualTo("brand", "Motorola")
    .whereEqualTo("brand", "Apple")
    .whereEqualTo("OS", "Marshmallow")
    .whereEqualTo("OS", "Nougat")
    .whereEqualTo("OS", "Oreo")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("RAM", 3)
```

Obviously it will not work because Firestore supports **Logical AND**, it neither supports **Logical OR** nor both combined. So what could be restructured way of modeling data to achieve this?

Comment: but you can use Start and end ..use query that start from 1000 and end at 2000 create node for price .?

Comment: price is fine, what about brands or Operation System. How to solve those?

Comment: create subcategories like brand->HP->laptops->price