# Not able to paginate firestore filter based query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in swift iOS which is using category based filters with Firestore as backend.
But this is loading only till 5 documents as per the first query while scrolling downwards and it is not loading more documents as it should happen in pagination.

The query used in this method is based on Category type Filter, Filter is of type either to fetch all documents or based on the category selected. When I use filtered query only two documents are loaded as per the second query in the below example

In stopObserving() function, it is supposed to remove the listener. but when the query is filtered and then when the filtered is removed it doesn't load back the unfiltered query.

I am just not able to load data in chunks. If any more details are required please let me know

**NEW ADDITION TO QUESTION**

With the Below code when filter is applied, **whereField()** clause is there in query and when filter is removed the same clause is also removed from the query, and without **whereField()** clause in query pagination is happening successfully, otherwise no pagination with **whereField()** clause in query

I also want the pagination with **whereField()** clause as it is happening without **whereField()** clause

CODE

```
fileprivate func observeQuery() {

  fetchingMore = true
  guard var query = query else { return }
  stopObserving()

  if posts.isEmpty {
    query = query.limit(to: 5)

    print("First 6 rides loaded")
  } else {
    query = query.start(afterDocument: lastDocumentSnapshot).limit(to: 2)
  }

  listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
      print("Error fetching snapshot results: \(error!)")
      return
    }
    let models = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Post in
      if let model = Post(dictionary: document.data()) {
        return model
      }
    }
    self.posts = models
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
      self.fetchingMore = false
    })

    self.lastDocumentSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last

    self.documents = snapshot.documents

    if self.documents.count > 0 {
      self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
    } else {
      self.tableView.backgroundView = self.backgroundView
    }

  }
}
```

Code for the whereField() query which updates the BaseQuery and then that  query is called in observeQuery() to get the documents and paginate them

```
extension HomeViewController: FiltersViewControllerDelegate {

  func query(withCategory category: String?) -> Query {
    var filtered = baseQuery()

    if category == nil {
      stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
      activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = true
    } else {
      stackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 44
      activeFiltersStackView.isHidden = false
    }

    // Advanced queries

    if let category = category, !category.isEmpty {
      filtered = filtered.whereField("category", isEqualTo: category)
    }

    return filtered
  }

  func controller(_ controller: FiltersViewController,
                  didSelectCategory category: String?
                  ) {
    let filtered = query(withCategory: category)

    if let category = category, !category.isEmpty {
      categoryFilterLabel.text = category
      categoryFilterLabel.isHidden = false
    } else {
      categoryFilterLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    self.query = filtered
    observeQuery()
  }

}
```

BaseQuery

```
fileprivate func baseQuery() -> Query {
  return Firestore.firestore().collection("collections").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm failing to fully understand what you intend to do and what you are getting, could you expand on that? Also take a look at [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#swift) and see if it helps you.

Comment: @Ajordat I am using filter in my tableview to get documents from the firestore successfully, but I am not able to paginate the data until now. the above code is not working it is loading only partially data. I trying to find the solution for the pagination in tableview where filters can be applied you can check the friendly eats example in firestore samples, the methodology I have applied here

Comment: What do you mean with partial data? I assume your intention is to load 5 documents and with pagination load 2 more each time, is that right? What are you currently getting? I have been checking the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-ios) you mention and the [resulting code](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-ios/blob/codelab-complete/FriendlyEats/RestaurantsTableViewController.swift) but I cannot see the pagination being performed there.

Comment: @Ajordat You understood right about the loading of the documents in pagination, what I exactly want. Right now only upto 5 documents are being retrieved from the database as per the above code and no further loading of data is being performed. In the code of codelabs there is no pagination is performed and I want to perform the pagination, with the above code when filter is applied, where() clause is there and when filter is removed the same clause is also removed from the query, and without where clause in query pagination is happening successfully, otherwise no pagination with where() clause

Comment: I understand your snippet works when there's no `where` condition. But the code you have shared doesn't have any `where` condition, does it mean that it works?

Comment: Also, would you mind providing where does `query` come from? Another thing that could prove useful is adding a `print` in the pagination condition, as I'm not completely sure that the `posts` variable that you check is the same `self.posts` variable that you set later with the loaded documents.

Comment: @Ajordat when there is no `whereField()` in query , pagination works. `posts` and `self.posts` are same . I have updated the question for the `whereField()` query

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will be grateful if you can help me in this kind of firebase pagination

Comment: Do you get any error message or it just retrieves nothing? I have reproduced your scenario (in Python) and I got a message stating that I need a composite index if I order by an attribute and later perform a `where` clause with an equality on a different field. After doing it I'm able to perform your query and get the desired results. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46821757/10810527) and its accepted answer to know more about this.

Comment: @Ajordat Thanks after composite index it started working and performing as desired.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to make it work. I have added the solution as an answer, please accept it so other people with the same issue can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is that you are trying to order by an attribute and perform a `where` clause with an "equals" condition on a different attribute.

If you want to perform this kind of operation you have to create a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for both attributes.